# Exclude Regular Expression Results

Tags: regex, preg-match, nsregularexpression

I want to delete all strings that i search
In my context I am looking for getString(@"blabla") and I want to remove others.
I wrote a regular expression for finding what I want
getString(@"(.*?)")
This regular expression retrieves what I want,i want to remove others

I give you a screenshoot

[image]

Comment: Using `preg_match_all` just get you matches using the regex you want to to match i.e. `/getString\(@"[^"]*"\)/`

Comment: yes,however i want to remove rest of strings

Comment: Once you get your matches rest is automatically removed.

Comment: thanks you solved my problem,i tried in php and i received what I want :)

Comment: Why do you use preg_match tag and show a SublimeText screenshot? If you need a solution in PHP please show your PHP code.

Comment: I dont use php code,I use sublime text,however php code worked for me!